# MAAS : Unable to import boot images

Tags: maas

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and when I run

```
maas root node-groups import-boot-images
```

all I get is

```
root@maas:~# maas xxxx node-groups import-boot-images

usage: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maascli/__main__.py [-h] COMMAND ...
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maascli/__main__.py: error: argument COMMAND: invalid choice: u'xxxx' (choose from u'list', u'login', u'logout', u'refresh')
```

when I run `maas-import-pxe-files` I get this error:

```
root@maas:~# maas-import-pxe-files

usage: maas-import-pxe-files [-h] --sources-file SOURCES_FILE
maas-import-pxe-files: error: argument --sources-file is required

root@maas:~# maas-import-pxe-files --sources-file /etc/maas/bootresources.yaml

2014-10-28 14:16:05,919 ERROR Unhandled exception; unable to continue.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/sbin/maas-import-pxe-files", line 30, in <module>
    main(args)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/import_images/boot_resources.py", line 269, in main
    sources = read_sources(args.sources_file)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/import_images/boot_resources.py", line 197, in read_sources
    return BootSources.load(filename=sources_yaml)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/config.py", line 349, in load
    return cls.parse(stream)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/config.py", line 343, in parse
    return cls.sources.to_python(yaml.safe_load(stream))

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/formencode/api.py", line 439, in to_python
    value = tp(value, state)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/formencode/compound.py", line 58, in _to_python
    to_python)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/formencode/foreach.py", line 102, in attempt_convert
    error_list=errors)

Invalid: Errors:
The input must be dict-like (not a <type 'str'>: 'boot')
```

and I don't get any images, same goes for the web ui.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

First login mass from console by using [this link](https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/maascli.html#cli).

Then from console:

```
sudo maas root node-groups import-boot-images
Import of boot images started on all cluster controllers
```